# Change label based on element visibility (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, text, replace, label, toggle

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Show next element</a>
<div>content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').toggle(function () {
    $(this).next().show();
},
function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

How do I change the above jQuery so it also changes the "Show" in the link to "Hide" when the element is visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasn't been tested...

```
$('a').toggle(function () {
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).html("Hide next element");
},
function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
    $(this).html("Show next element");
});
```

Comment: I figured it a sec ago. .text() is better, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Nimbuz .text() only if you aren't including HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').toggle(function () {

    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).html('Hide next element');
},
function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
    $(this).html('Show next element');
});
```